# How can I prevent the time of day from appearing on a date in a cell?

Tags: excel, vba, datetime, globalization, ms-project

I have a macro that sets a cell to a date value pulled from a task object from the MS Project API like this:

```
Sub Example(t as MSProject.Task, row As Integer, column As Integer)
    
    dim dt as Date
    dt = t.Start 'start date of a Microsoft Project task being accessed via the MS Project API

    ActiveSheet.Cells(row, column) = dt

End Sub
```

the regional date format follows a day - month - year convention so the value of `dt` can be something like this: `#13/03/2023 08:00:00#`

I've set the number format on the cells I'm writing to as this: "dd/MM/yyyy", so I would expect the date value to appear to look like this: 13/03/2023 (Including the time in formula bar but not on the display text of the cell).

However the time of day seems to always be displayed in the cell when the day value is greater than 12. otherwise, it follows the correct format. Here's an example of what I'm seeing:

[image: dates]

The time of day will disappear from the cell when I enter and then exit edit mode in the cell (either by clicking into the formula bar or clicking F2 on my keyboard).

Here's a video:
https://www.loom.com/share/818e0f287018461a8eb6d726ff8e244b?sid=dd367cd7-a0bd-43ef-8c85-38ea78afd696

What gives? how can I prevent this and make the time value not be displayed in these cells when the day value is greater than 12?

I've tried just converting the date variable to a string value using the `cStr()` method but Excel always ends up storing the value as a date in the cell and flips the day and month values whenever the day value of the date variable is less than 12. So 06/03/2023 (6th of March, 2023) becomes 03/06/2023 (3rd of June, 2023), which obviously is a problem.

I've also tried converting the date variable into a long but when I do this I lose the time, and I want to include the time in the cell's value, I just don't want it to be displayed on the text of the cell if the number format does not include the time.

Comment: Where is `#13/03/2023 08:00:00#` coming from, is it user entered ?

Comment: Try changing the function code line in `ActiveSheet.Cells(row, column) = Format(dt,"dd/mm/yyyy")`. Theoretically, it must work as you think, but being an anomaly, you should force it writing the wished format.

Comment: @CDP1802, it's being pulled from a database

Comment: For the value showing `11/04/23` in excel what is the value extracted from the database., is it `#04/11/2023 08:00#` ?.

Comment: @FaneDuru I've tried that but Excel then always tries to flip the month and year values when the day value is less than 12

Comment: @CDP1802 #11/04/2023 17:00:00#

Comment: I see 'SSI Tool for Excel' Add-In. Can you disable it temporary and test?

Comment: I have no such behaviuor.

Comment: *pulled from a database* - is that using sql and `adodb`, if so which database vendor MSSQL Server, Oracle , MySQL ?

Comment: @rotabor  SSI Tools for Excel is my tool that pulls the dates

Comment: @CDP1802 database wasn't exactly the correct term I should have used. The date values are pulled from Microsoft Project schedule files using the MS Project API. They always include the time.

Comment: If Excel tries flipping the month with the day, it look that what you name database **keeps the Date in that way**. Can you see it? Can you check it, from this point of view? Try adding in the function `Debut.Print dt`. What does it return?

Comment: Are you sure the date showing as 11/04/23 in excel is also showing as 11/04/2023 in MS Project .? It seems like excel is trying to read the dates as mm/dd/yyyy but retaining as strings those with 1st part greater than 12. If that is the case I would expect the 11/04 to be 04/11 in MSP.

Comment: Your problem stems from the fact that the "dates with M>12" are actually text strings, and the other dates are being converted **incorrectly**. Excel thinks the dates being entered are in `MDY` format whereas, in reality, they are `DMY` format. To fix this, you need to change your method of getting the dates into Excel so Excel knows the incoming dates are in `DMY` format. Then they will be properly interpreted as dates and you will be able to format them as you wish. This is a **very** common mistake. How, exactly, does the data get into Excel.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld The dates are being pulled from Microsoft Project files using the MS Project API. These values I'm pulling from MS Project are `Date` data types. So I'm taking those values and then setting them to the value of the Excel cell.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I updated the code sample so it's more similar to what I am doing.

Comment: Haven't worked with that API. But, from what I read, you may have to change the Date Format in **Microsoft Project** to be the same as in your **Windows Regional Settings**, or to be unambiguous, in order for Excel to interpret the date correctly. I'd suggest trying either `dd-mm-yyyy` or if this will be used on computers with varying Windows Regional settings, try `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld the date format in Microsoft Project (on my computer) is following the same date format as the Windows Regional Settings: dd/MM/yyyy. The `t.Start` property returns data as a `Date` data type. I've tested it for accuracy by using the `Day()`, `Month()`  and `Year()` methods and confirmed it is returning the correct values.

Comment: Also, what version of SSI Tools are you using? In looking at documentation, it seems SSI tools will generally use US settings for dates for versions prior to `13.5.0 09-21-2021`. Even with that version, there may be some setting in SSI Tools that is not correct.

Comment: How exactly did you confirm that month and day were correct for `t.start`. IMO, best would be something like `debug.print Format(t.start, "yyyy-mmm-dd")` where `dd` is both less than and greater than 12. That should print an unambiguous date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the only way to get around this is to touch each cell. For example:

```
Dim c As Range
For Each c In ActiveSheet.Range("A2:B7")
    Dim d As Date
    d = CDate(c) + 0
    c = d
Next c
```

The only way I could replicate the issue was to use the Task [StartText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.task.starttext) property (e.g. `t.StartText`) rather than the task Start property (`t.Start`). However, using that gave the same results as shown in the question so with luck this solution will work.

It's worth noting that while working within the user interface, adding 0 to the whole range at once using PasteSpecial: Add worked but doing so in vba did not.

Comment: this worked! but only if I run it after all the values had been written to the worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

A good advice with excel and date time is to use doubles
instead of a date give the double value of the date to the cell:45203.665 will result in the format of the cell. Good to use value2 property

Try:
ActiveCell.Value2 = 45203.665

Comment: When a date is converted to a double or a long, does it still include the time? I need the time to still be included in the dates value, I just don't want it to be displayed in the text of the cell if the user has the date format to something like this: "dd/MM/yyyy"

Comment: Double includes the time. The int part is the date, the fractional part is the time of the day.

Comment: Test this advice, please.

Comment: I just tested this and it still printed out the time on the cells for any date that has a day value greater than 12

Answer (score 0):

Try parsing the date as a string

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Example(t As MSProject.Task, row As Integer, column As Integer)
     'start date of a Microsoft Project task being accessed via the MS Project API
    ActiveSheet.Cells(row, column) = ParseDMY(CStr(t.Start))
End Sub

Function ParseDMY(s As String) As Date
    Dim ar, arDMY
    ar = Split(Trim(s), " ")
    arDMY = Split(ar(0), "/")
    ParseDMY = DateSerial(arDMY(2), arDMY(1), arDMY(0)) + TimeValue(ar(1))
End Function
```